# jQuery sortable lists to exact position/place

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

Is it possible with jQuery sortable to make 2 lists, one source and one destination list. I would like to move items from source list to exact position to destination list. For example, source list has 10 items, destination list is empty but has 10 places. Then, I want to drag and drop item from source list to target list on position 4.

Maybe this image illustrate this better:
[image]

Thank you!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#source, #target").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectList",
  }).disableSelection();

});
```

```css
ul li {
  background-color: #d6d3d3;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px; 
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}

#source {
  float: left;
  list-style:  none;
}

#target {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ul class="sortable-list connectList" id="source">
  <li class="warning-element">
    First
  </li>
  <li class="success-element">
    Second
  </li>
  <li class="info-element">
    Third
  </li>
  <li class="danger-element">
    Fourth
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="sortable-list connectList" id="target">
  <li class="success-element">
    One
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: there are lot of  lists... could you show your html code and what have you tried?

Comment: I posted code below in answer. It works ok to move items from one list to another, but I don't know how to make target list looks like on image above, how to "reserve" places for items from source list.

Comment: i have done a snippet of your code , but il misses something to have like your picture (css). so you could delete your answer

Comment: Hi, thank you for snippet. I have edited it and added css. But my question is how to ensure something like image above shows - so I can put item from source list to exact position in target list. Now I can only put item at the end of target list, and then sort target list. But I can't add item to third place so I have empty second place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not the complete solution, but you could begin with that:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#target li").remove();
  $("#source li").clone().appendTo("#target");
  $("#target li").text("").addClass("empty");

  $("#source li").draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    appendTo: 'body',
    helper: function(ev, ui) {
      return "<span class='helperPick'>" + $(this).html() + "</span>";
    },
    start: function(ev, ui) {
      ui.helper.width($(this).width());
    } // ensure helper width
  });

  $("#target .empty").droppable({
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    hoverClass: 'highlight',
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
      var item = ui.draggable;
      if (!ui.draggable.closest('.empty').length) item = item.clone().draggable(); // if item was dragged from the source list - clone it
      this.innerHTML = ''; // clean the placeholder
      item.css({
        top: -10,//to substract margin and pading
        left: -10
      }).appendTo(this); // append item to placeholder
    }
  });

/*
    $("#source, #target").sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectList",
    }).disableSelection();
*/
});
```

```css
ul li {
  background-color: #d6d3d3;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}

#source {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}

#target {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}

.empty {
  width: 100px;
  height: 18px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px dashed #999;
}

.empty .item {
  margin: 0;
}

.empty .item .closer {
  display: block;
}

.helperPick {border:1px dashed red; height:20px; line-height:20px; text-align:center; width:120px}
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ul class="sortable-list connectList" id="source">
  <li class="warning-element">
    First
  </li>
  <li class="success-element">
    Second
  </li>
  <li class="info-element">
    Third
  </li>
  <li class="danger-element">
    Fourth
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="sortable-list connectList" id="target">
  <li class="success-element">
    One
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I know how to create empty elements in list, but i don't need this. This empty elements should be only placeholders or something and when I drop item on position 2, there should be same number of elements in target list like before, not +1 (that dropped), but only change is that element on position 2 is real element, not empty element.

Comment: @user2204356 i have understood its just the basis of work..i have updated the work,  i am not sure you could easily do that with sortable without extend the widget (very complex), here its soltuion drag and drop

Comment: thank you very much. This is something I want. I appreciate your work and help! Thanks one more time.

Comment: to use sortable to do that: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12221179/jquery-ui-sortable-add-placeholders-to-lists-to-simulate-empty-spaces  the answer with fiddle linked http://jsfiddle.net/vfezJ/, really complex to understand

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look at this link also. I was searching for something like that but did not find. Thank you one more time and I owe you a beer ;)

Comment: if you want to keep the sortable option for each list and not for drag an drop, just activate sortable when you need it... its another question if you dont find

Comment: Yes, yes, I understand and I think that I can do that if I need ;) Thanks one more time for your effort